# How to set up Intel C++ Composer XE for Mathematica for Windows?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I tried

```
    Needs["CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`"]

    greeter = CreateExecutable[StringJoin["#include <stdio.h>\n", "int main(){\n", "  printf(\"Hello world.\\n\");\n", "}\n"], "hiworld", "Compiler" -> IntelCompiler, "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Composer XE 2011 SP1\\bin\\ia32", "CompilerName" -> "icl.exe"]
```

But get an error:

```
    CreateExecutable::instl: The compiler installation directive "CompilerInstallation" -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\bin\ia32 does not indicate a usable installation of Intel Compiler. >>
```

EDIT:

```
    In[776]:= CCompilers[Full]

    Out[776]= {{"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", "Compiler" -> IntelCompiler, "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler",  "Compiler" -> CompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,   "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}

    In[777]:= CCompilers[]
    Out[777]= {}
```

It seems MMA didn't find the compiler even after I specified its location.

Did I miss any point here?

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html#394172820

Comment: The answer is : install C compiler !

Comment: @Artes I did. I installed Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 SP1, the upgrade of the old Intel C++ compiler. But it seems MMA don't recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with

```
  Needs["CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`"]
```

check if you have installed `IntelCompiler` :

```
   CCompilers[Full]
```

in my case I get something like this :

```
 {{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
   "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0", 
   "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {...other compilers...},
   {"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", "Compiler" -> IntelCompiler, 
    "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
```

and evaluating your input `greeter=...`
  the error message is like in your case.

Instead, copying from the output of  `CCompilers[Full]` proper installation

```
In[1]:= Needs["CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`"]
In[2]:= greeter =  CreateExecutable[ StringJoin["#include <stdio.h>\n", 
       "int main(){\n","  printf(\"Hello world.\\n\");\n", "}\n"], "hiworld", 
        "Compiler" -> VisualStudioCompiler, "CompilerInstallation" -> 
        "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0", "CompilerName" -> "Automatic"]

Out[2]= "C:\\Users\\spindoctor\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\\
             SystemFiles\\LibraryResources\\Windows\\hiworld.exe"
```

I get  that executable.